# BASIC random function giving a syntax error, not sure what the problem is

Tags: random, basic, picaxe

It's saying the error is just after the 11 but I can't figure it out please help

```
11 * RND(1) + 1;a

if a = 1 then let pinsb = 01110111  
if a = 2 then let pinsb = 00010100  
if a = 3 then let pinsb = 10110011  
if a = 4 then let pinsb = 10110110
if a = 5 then let pinsb = 11010100  
if a = 6 then let pinsb = 11100110
if a= 7 then let pinsb = 11100111   
if a = 8 then let pinsb = 00110100  
if a = 9 then let pinsb = 11110111  
if a = 10 then let pinsb = 11110100
```

Comment: In the first line try **a=11*rnd(1)+1** instead

Comment: Also declare &B for binary values, for example, pinsb=&B01110111

Comment: To be clear, is this PICAXE BASIC?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this question is about the [PICAXE microcontroller](http://www.picaxe.com/) and its BASIC language, because of the `[picaxe]` tag. There are several things in the posted code that won't work in PICAXE BASIC so I guess you're familiar with a different dialect or are trying to take some code written for a different dialect and use it on a PICAXE. If this isn't the case, please let us know.

To get this code to work on a PICAXE you need to fix a few things:

- You can't just assign to a new variable name; you need to use the built-in names `b0`, `b1`, `b2` etc (byte variables) or `w0`, `w1`, `w2` etc (word variables) unless you define another name for it using the `symbol` keyword.
- To generate a random number, use the `random` keyword which assigns a random value to the word variable you specify.
- You can only use the one-line `if … then` command with `goto`, `gosub` or `exit`. Otherwise you need to use an `if … then … endif` structure, but you can write this on a single line using `:` to separate the commands.
- Finally, to specify a binary value you prefix it with a `%` character.

So I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
symbol a = w0             ; use the name 'a' for word variable w0
random a                  ; assign a random value of 0...65535 to a
a = a // 10 + 1           ; // is modulo i.e. remainder of a / 10, so result is in range 1 - 10

if a = 1 then : pinsB = %01110111 : endif 
if a = 2 then : pinsB = %00010100 : endif
if a = 3 then : pinsB = %10110011 : endif
if a = 4 then : pinsB = %10110110 : endif
if a = 5 then : pinsB = %11010100 : endif 
if a = 6 then : pinsB = %11100110 : endif
if a = 7 then : pinsB = %11100111 : endif
if a = 8 then : pinsB = %00110100 : endif
if a = 9 then : pinsB = %11110111 : endif
if a = 10 then : pinsB = %11110100 : endif
```

Always remember that each word variable is made up of two byte variables, so if you've used `w0` you can't also use `b0` or `b1` at the same time, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assign binary values based on a random value:

This program was written in QB64 which supports &B prefix whereas QB45 does not.

```
REM assign binary values based on a random value
a = INT(RND * 10 + 1)

IF a = 1 THEN LET pinsb = &B1110111
IF a = 2 THEN LET pinsb = &B10100
IF a = 3 THEN LET pinsb = &B10110011
IF a = 4 THEN LET pinsb = &B10110110
IF a = 5 THEN LET pinsb = &B11010100
IF a = 6 THEN LET pinsb = &B11100110
IF a = 7 THEN LET pinsb = &B11100111
IF a = 8 THEN LET pinsb = &B110100
IF a = 9 THEN LET pinsb = &B11110111
IF a = 10 THEN LET pinsb = &B11110100
```

Comment: Although the LET keyword is not longer used or necessary.

Comment: I'm confused. The question is tagged [picaxe], not [quickbasic] or [qb64]. None of your answers will work in PICAXE BASIC. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the PICAXE tag and assumed you were using QB.

Answer (score 0):

Assign binary values based on a random value using a binary convert function:

```
REM assign binary values based on a random value using a binary convert function
A = INT(RND * 10 + 1)
IF A = 1 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("1110111")
IF A = 2 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("10100")
IF A = 3 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("10110011")
IF A = 4 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("10110110")
IF A = 5 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("11010100")
IF A = 6 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("11100110")
IF A = 7 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("11100111")
IF A = 8 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("110100")
IF A = 9 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("11110111")
IF A = 10 THEN pinsb = GetBinary("11110100")
END
FUNCTION GetBinary (B$)
    FOR V = LEN(B$) TO 1 STEP -1
        IF MID$(B$, V, 1) = "1" THEN
            X# = X# + 2 ^ (V - 1)
        END IF
    NEXT
    GetBinary = X#
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: Use this if you are not running QB64.

Answer (score 0):

Assign binary values based on a random value using a binary
convert function reading values from data.

```
REM assign binary values based on a random value using a binary
REM convert function reading values from data.
RANDOMIZE TIMER ' reseed rnd
A = INT(RND * 10 + 1)
RESTORE
FOR X = 1 TO A
    READ X$
NEXT
pinsb = GetBinary(X$)
PRINT "pinsb="; pinsb
END
DATA "1110111","10100","10110011","10110110","11010100"
DATA "11100110","11100111","110100","11110111","11110100"
FUNCTION GetBinary (B$)
    FOR V = LEN(B$) TO 1 STEP -1
        IF MID$(B$, V, 1) = "1" THEN
            X# = X# + 2 ^ (V - 1)
        END IF
    NEXT
    GetBinary = X#
END FUNCTION
```